# Degrees of freedom for a t-test with derived variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, degrees-of-freedom

I have a derived variable y = A-B-C+D, and I want to determine if its mean is greater than 0. I'm having trouble determining the number of degrees of freedom to use in a t-test.

In the experiments, I measure A, B, C, and D separately. They are independent, i.e., unpaired (or unquadrupled). I can calculate the uncertainty in y through propagation of uncertainty, for use in finding the t statistic.

If I had z = A-B, then asking if z>0 is the same as asking if A>B, which I can answer using a 2-sample t test. In that case, the degrees of freedom for the t test includes both initial variables: dof = n_A + n_B - 2.

So for y, which is derived from 4 variables, should the dof still include all measurements? Would it be dof = n_A + n_B + n_C + n_D - 4?

Comment: How do you match up the A, B, C, and D observations to add them up? That is, why not scramble all of the D observations and add them up that way?

Comment: Dave's question is critical; if you think about it carefully you will have the answer to your question.

Comment: If I'm interpreting your question correctly @Da

Comment: To be sure I'm interpreting your question correctly @Dave, are you asking how the D observations are matched to the A,B,C observations? They actually aren't – I'm measuring and averaging the observations for each variable separately. I believe if they were matched, that would make the paired t-test more valid, but in my case I want to use an unpaired test.

To add some more context, I'm calculating the t-statistic directly (t = <y> / (s / sqrt(n)), where s is the error-propagated uncertainty, s = sqrt(s_A^2 + s_B^2 + s_C^2 + s_D^2

Comment: And n, I believe, is the number of observations per variable (same for all), although I'm not sure if that's right either. 

<y> = <A> + <B> + <C> + <D>, so the order of observations doesn't matter.

Then I'm calculating the p-value directly from the t cdf, but for that I need the degrees of freedom, and I'm not sure if all observations of all variables count as degrees of freedom, or if it's only the number of observations per variable.

Comment: How do you find your $y$ if there is no matching between the variables added together to form $y?$

Comment: Average the observations for each variable separately. So the estimate of _y_ is the average of _A_ minus the average of _B_ minus the average of _C_ plus the average of _D_. (I forgot the negatives in the previous comment.) Since the combination is linear, the order of observations doesn't matter.

Comment: It's like if you wanted to know how many more mice a cat catches per day than a dog. You'd average all the cat observations separately from all the dog observations. Except here I have 4 variables, not just 2.